# Advanced search: disjunction of tags

Tags: stackexchange-api

I would like to make advanced search on tags using a disjunction (instead of the default conjunction).

For example, I would like [tagged=python-asyncio;python-trio](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search#fromdate=2020-06-28&order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=python-asyncio%3Bpython-trio&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true) to return a superset of the results from [tagged=python-asyncio](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search#fromdate=2020-06-28&order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=python-asyncio&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true).

But instead, for the two tags together I have:

```
{
  "items": [],
}
```

and for `python-asyncio` alone I have:

```
"items": [
    {
      "tags": [
        "python",
        "redis",
        "python-asyncio",
        "publish-subscribe"
      ],
      "some more stuff"
    },
    "more questions"
]
```

This is a bit strange as the documentation suggests it should return the union of results from the two tags:

> `tagged` - a semicolon delimited list of tags, of which at least one will be present on all returned questions.

Is this possible to achieve without making multiple requests?

Comment: You have set a fromdate parameter and I don't see any questions tagged with both tags after June 28th. What is wrong?

Comment: I don't want questions with both tags I want questions that contains any of the two tags.

Comment: This what this method returns, though: questions tagged with both tags.

Comment: Yes, I know that's the content of my question. That's why I ask how to make it return a disjunction (union) instead of the conjunction (intersection).

Comment: Use q (works like the search box here, probably...) https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search#pagesize=100&fromdate=2020-06-26&order=desc&sort=activity&q=%5Bpython-trio%5D%20or%20%5Bpython-asyncio%5D&filter=!9_bDE.BDp&site=stackoverflow&run=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `q` parameter, while not documented, allows most of the search options. In search, you use `[x] or [y]` to get questions tagged either [x](/questions/tagged/x), [y](/questions/tagged/y) or both. You therefore need to set `q` to [`[python-trio] or [python-asyncio]`](//api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/advanced?pagesize=100&fromdate=1593129600&order=desc&sort=activity&q=%5Bpython-trio%5D%20or%20%5Bpython-asyncio%5D&site=stackoverflow&filter=!9_bDE.BDp&key=U4DMV*8nvpm3EOpvf69Rxw((), as you'd do in [search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-trio+or+python-asyncio).